# Deleting Registry entries using reg delete

Tags: batch-file, registry, dos

I am trying to delete registry values using `reg delete` in a batch command. The problem I am having is that I can't delete the value.  Here is what I am trying:

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports\" /v C:\convertdoc\output\SilentPrintTemp\126017829image-gif3.ps
```

Ideally I wanna remove all entries with:

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports\" /v  C:\convertdoc\output\SilentPrintTemp\*.ps
```

I have tried it in a few different ways and with different parameters. Normally the double "" stops the command at the end of the key. So maybe my syntax is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Save this with a `.bat` extension and run it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ports=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports"

rem get only the first token of each line of "reg query"
for /f %%I in (
    'reg query "%ports%"'
) do (
    echo(%%I | findstr /i "c:\\convertdoc\\output\\silentprinttemp\\.*\.ps" >NUL && (
        rem (if "findstr" didn't exit with an abnormal error code)
        echo Deleting item %%I
        reg delete "%ports%" /v "%%I" /f
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank's so much rojo. I assume my lack of experience and my start into scripting was why i didn't know about the command reg query. I will study your script and learn it. Do you have any good references to learn knowledge about batch scripting?

Comment: @user2287626 - If my answer has helped you, please consider clicking the check mark to mark it as accepted.  If I recall correctly, there's a beginner guide at ss64.com that some have said is worthwhile.  For the most part, if there is anything you are interested in learning to do, google it, search this site, and generally look at the code people use to solve problems.  If you want to understand more about a specific command (such as `reg`), opening a `cmd` prompt and typing `reg /?` is a great way to learn.

Comment: that script doesn't work properly it searches for the vaule and I see how the script works but its not deleting the values.Thanks for all the help I will definitely checkout ss64.com

Comment: @Dk6861636b - Are any error messages present?  Does the account under which your batch script runs have rights to delete those registry values according to the ACL / security of the `HKLM\etc...\Ports` key?

Comment: @Dk6861636b - That's helpful. You know what happens when you make an assumption? I made an assumption. I'm sorry, Dk. I was wrong. You were right. The registry item names *must be* the filesystem paths. Try this revised code and see whether it works better for you.

Comment: Still receiving a error about finding the Value name. Here is the output http://pastebin.com/JZgF35T5

Comment: Could the problem be the argument /v has to be added? If so how would that look in the code.

Comment: @Dk6861636b - Oh, geez.  I just realized that I had the syntax of the `reg delete` command wrong.  Turns out `wmic` wasn't needed at all.  I fixed my `reg delete` command and it works using the simpler command.  I'm sorry I made you struggle so much this morning for my own inability to read help documentation.  `:x`

Comment: What was wrong just so I can learn will you post the wrong and write code again on here

Comment: @Dk6861636b - You had already guessed, but I ignored it.  You said in an earlier comment, *"Could the problem be the argument /v has to be added? If so how would that look in the code."*  The answer is, yes, the problem was that I didn't have the `/v` argument before, but was just smashing the item name onto the end of the path.  You can see the [previous revisions of my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16046323/revisions).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have been more than helpful. I have learned a lot today.

Comment: @Dk6861636b - I'm not sure how that is, as you've been right more often than I have.  You should be teaching me.  `:>`

Comment: Hey @rojo do you know after its done deleting how I would set a specific printer to a port? In my case its the default printer and I want port FILE:

Comment: Trying to do something like this:

Comment: rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /r "FILE:"

Comment: I'm sorry Dk, I've never programmatically messed with printer entries.  That might be worth asking in another question though.