# How to delete several values in registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, dos

I'm trying to delete certain registry values. I've used [the code (by "rojo")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044267/deleting-registry-entries-using-reg-delete).

1. This code works perfectly if you define the exact key. For example, I want to delete Logon.vbs from the Run key. If I also want to delete Logoff.vbs, it seems I cannot use *.vbs to delete those two. How would I do that (deleting multiple keys with the same extension)?
2. A related question is how to delete a key that holds certain data. For example, I have a key named Logon which contains data to C:\Windows\Logon.vbs. I want that key deleted as well. When using the example above, this did not work.

I have permission(s) on those keys, so that's not the issue. What am I missing or doing wrong?

As an example I've provided a screenshot where example (1) is represented by the red color and (2) by blue. Screenshot:
[image: Regedit screenshot]

The code in my first example would look like:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "DisableScripts=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

rem get only the first token of each line of "reg query"
for /f %%I in (
    'reg query "%DisableScripts%"'
) do (
    echo(%%I | findstr /i "Logon.vbs" >NUL && (
        rem (if "findstr" didn't exit with an abnormal error code)
        echo Deleting item %%I
        reg delete "%DisableScripts%" /v "%%I" /f
    )
```

This deletes the key "Logon.vbs" just fine. However, I also want to delete "Logoff.vbs". I have tried with "*.vbs", but to no avail.

The code above does also not delete the "Script" value where the Data contains Logon.vbs. I suppose I would somehow have to use the **/d** switch for that...

Comment: you should add examples to your questions.

Comment: Hi Endoro, you are right, I've added an example and some extra information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I've posted the solution below but I can't seem to figure out how to delete those keys with a certain value in the Data field....

Anyone? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code  for the first example:

```
for /f %%a in ('reg query "%DisableScripts%" /s^|findstr /ic:"\.vbs "') do echo reg delete "%DisableScripts%" /v "%%~a" /f
```

---

Code for the second example:

```
for /f %%a in ('reg query "%DisableScripts%" /s^|findstr /eic:"C:\\logon\.vbs"') do echo reg delete "%DisableScripts%" /v "%%~a" /f
```

Please note the Regex expressions `"\.vbs "` and `"C:\\logon\.vbs"`. Use a command line with administrator permissions.

Comment: Thanks Endoro! When using: /s^findstr /ic:"\.vbs" it deletes both keys with vbs in Data field as keys which have .vbs in their name.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm not sure how I missed this. Of course you have to append **%** .... Below the code to delete all VBS files under the \Run key:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "DisableScripts=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

rem get only the first token of each line of "reg query"
for /f %%I in (
    'reg query "%DisableScripts%"'
) do (
    echo(%%I | findstr /i "%*.vbs" >NUL && (
        rem (if "findstr" didn't exit with an abnormal error code)
        echo Deleting item %%I
        reg delete "%DisableScripts%" /v "%%I" /f
    )
(
```

I'll be checking later on how to delete certain data from the Data field and post back here.